# Capturing the replaced text using re.sub in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to create a report for all the text replacements done by the program using `re.sub`. I am not able to figure out how can I capture the replaced text in to a variable. Can any of you please help me in doing this?    Please find the below code

```
import re

Report_file = open("report.txt", "w")
st = '''<item><AP>item1</AP><AP>Item2</AP><AP>item3</AP><AP>Item4</AP></item>'''

outval = re.sub(r'(?i)item1', "value1", st)
outval = re.sub(r'(?i)item2', "value2", outval)
outval = re.sub(r'(?i)item3', "value3", outval)  
print outval
```

I want the report file in the below format

```
OLD: item1
NEW: value1

OLD: item2
NEW: value2

OLD: item3
NEW: value3
```

Comment: I posted an answer that does the job with a more simple and convenient method

Comment: Could you, please, tell me if you looked at my better solution ?

Comment: @eyquem Accepted your answer  Thanks for giving me the simple solution. when you get a chance can you please help me on this. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957713/writing-substituted-text-in-to-a-external-file)

Comment: Thank you. I take a look in your linked problem. - A first thing I can say: don't use name _"string"_ as identifier or parameter, for ``str`` is a reserved keyword in Python.

Comment: I have the solution to your linked problem. The thread is closed, you should post the answer again and I would immediatly post the answer before it will maybe be closed. Warn me by a comment here before posting, please

Comment: @eyquem Can i post the question now?

Comment: @eyquem PLease find the [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981583/search-patterns-replacement-using-lambda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question and in the answer, you'll have to write as many instructions

```
outval = re.sub(r'(?i)item3', .......... )
```

as there are items to replace.

What if there are 56 items to replace ?

.

In my following solution , there are 5 items to replace, but the instruction
   `r.sub(fruiting,text)` is written only one time:

```
text = '''
OR 125
BA  48
Pr 12
ba 4
Cherry 147
Ba   10
Or 7
OR 6
Orange 2
AP 9
PR          3
Banana 101
or 22
pR 13
'''
```

.
    import re

```
the_items = ('OR','BA','AP','PR','CH')
new_items = ('Orange','Banana','Apple','Pear','Cherry')
corresp = dict(zip(the_items,new_items))

r = re.compile('(%s) *(\d+)' % '|'.join(the_items),
               re.IGNORECASE)

def fruiting(ma,longname = corresp):
    fresh = '%-12s %s' % (longname[ma.group(1).upper()],
                          ma.group(2) ) 
    tu = ('OLD: %r\n'
          'NEW: %r\n'
          %
          ( ma.group(),fresh) )
    print tu
    return fresh

print '%s%s' % (text, r.sub(fruiting,text))
```

result

```
OLD: 'OR 125'
NEW: 'Orange       125'

OLD: 'BA  48'
NEW: 'Banana       48'

OLD: 'Pr 12'
NEW: 'Pear         12'

OLD: 'ba 4'
NEW: 'Banana       4'

OLD: 'Ba   10'
NEW: 'Banana       10'

OLD: 'Or 7'
NEW: 'Orange       7'

OLD: 'OR 6'
NEW: 'Orange       6'

OLD: 'AP 9'
NEW: 'Apple        9'

OLD: 'PR          3'
NEW: 'Pear         3'

OLD: 'or 22'
NEW: 'Orange       22'

OLD: 'pR 13'
NEW: 'Pear         13'
```

.

```
OR 125
BA  48
Pr 12
ba 4
Cherry 147
Ba   10
Or 7
OR 6
Orange 2
AP 9
PR          3
Banana 101
or 22
pR 13

Orange       125
Banana       48
Pear         12
Banana       4
Cherry 147
Banana       10
Orange       7
Orange       6
Orange 2
Apple        9
Pear         3
Banana 101
Orange       22
Pear         13
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a function instead of a replace pattern instead:

```
def build_replacer(replacement):
    def replace(match):
        print match.group(), replacement
        return replacement
    return replace
```

Then run:

```
outval = re.sub(r'(?i)item1', build_replacer("value1"), st)
outval = re.sub(r'(?i)item2', build_replacer("value2"), outval)
outval = re.sub(r'(?i)item3', build_replacer("value3"), outval)
```

and it'll print the original text and it's replacement.

This then gives:

```
>>> st = '''<item><AP>item1</AP><AP>Item2</AP><AP>item3</AP><AP>Item4</AP></item>'''
>>> outval = re.sub(r'(?i)item1', build_replacer("value1"), st)
item1 value1
>>> outval = re.sub(r'(?i)item2', build_replacer("value2"), outval)
Item2 value2
>>> outval = re.sub(r'(?i)item3', build_replacer("value3"), outval)  
item3 value3
>>> outval
'<item><AP>value1</AP><AP>value2</AP><AP>value3</AP><AP>Item4</AP></item>'
```

Instead of printing you could also store that information elsewhere, of course.

The `build_replacer()` function just returns a new function, `replace()`, which is what `re.sub()` will use whenever it finds a match. Instead of directly replacing the matched text, it asks the function what to use as a replacement text.

The reason we use `build_replacer()` here as a nested function, is so we can store the fixed replacement text somewhere and re-use the same replacement function over and over again without having to hardcode the replacement text.

Comment: Hello @Martijn. Can you explain a little how and when is that function `replace` getting invoked? Since `build_replace` is just return a function object, I'm finding it hard to understand, how that is used in invocation.

Comment: @RohitJain: Added a short explanation. It's a nested function, using the scope to store the replacement text.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Thanks for your reply. It worked fine. But can you please explain the function once ? what is the input that you are passing to replace function?