# Search Patterns replacement using lambda

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to write into a file with Before and after search replacement patterns. I have written the below code. I have used function in writing to output file and it worked fine. But i have around 20 such replacement patterns and i feel i am not writing a good code because i need to create functions for all those replacements. Can you please let me know is there any other way in implementing this?

```
import re

Report_file = open("report.txt", "w")
st = '''<TimeLog>
<InTime='10Azx'>1056789</InTime>
<OutTime='14crg'>1056867</OutTime>
<PsTime='32lxn'>1056935</PsTime>
<ClrTime='09zvf'>1057689</ClrTime>
</TimeLog>'''

def tcnv(str):
     Report_file.write("Previous TS:  " + str + "\n\n")
     v1 = re.search(r"(?i)<clrtime='(\d+\w+)'>", str)
     val1 = v1.group(1)

     v2 = re.search(r"(?i)(<clrtime='(\d+\w+)'>(.*?)</clrtime>)", str)
     val2 = v2.group(3)

     soutval = "<Clzone><clnvl='" + val1 + "'>" + val2 + "</clnvl></Clzone>" 
     Report_file.write("New TS:  " + soutval + "\n")
     return soutval


st = re.sub(r"(?i)(<clrtime='(\d+\w+)'>(.*?)</clrtime>)", lambda m: tcnv(m.group(1)), st)
st = re.sub(r"(?i)<intime='(\d+\w+)'>(.*?)</intime>", "<Izone><Invl='\\1'>\\2</Invl></Izone>", st)
st = re.sub(r"(?i)<outtime='(\d+\w+)'>(.*?)</outtime>", "<Ozone><onvl='\\1'>\\2</onnvl></Ozone>", st)
st = re.sub(r"(?i)<pstime='(\d+\w+)'>(.*?)</pstime>", "<Pszone><psnvl='\\1'>\\2</psnvl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see why you put the re.IGNORECASE flag under the form of `(?i)`, so I don't use it the following solution, and the pattern is written with the uppercased letters where necessary according to your sample

Note that you should use the `with` statement to open the files, it would be far better:

```
with open('filename.txt','rb') as f:

    ch = f.read()
```

The answer

```
 import re

 st = '''<InTime='10Azx'>1056789</InTime>
 <OutTime='14crg'>1056867</OutTime>
 <PsTime='32lxn'>1056935</PsTime>
 <ClrTime='09zvf'>1057689</ClrTime>
 '''

 d = dict(zip(('InTime','OutTime','PsTime','ClrTime'),

              (('Izone><Invl','/Invl></Izone'),
               ('Ozone><onvl','/onnvl></Ozone'),
               ('Pszone><psnvl','/psnvl></Pszone'),
               ('Clzone><clnvl','/clnvl></Clzone'))
              )
          )

 def ripl(ma,d=d):
      return "<{}='{}'>{}<{}>".format(d[ma.group(1)][0],
                                      ma.group(2),
                                      ma.group(3),
                                      d[ma.group(1)][1])

 st2 = re.sub(r"<(InTime|OutTime|PsTime|ClrTime)='(\d+\w+)'>(.*?)</\1>",
             ripl, st)

 print '%s\n\n%s\n' % (st,st2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. since i am new to python i am opening the files in that way. can you please explain the ripl function?

Comment: I am not able to create report which contains before and after search replacement patterns.

Comment: @new2python ``ripl()`` is a function intended to receive MatchObjects on the parameter ``ma``. It uses a dictionary ``d``. I put this dictionary as a default value for the parameter ``d``. In fact the function could be defined by ``def ripl(ma,dico):`` and the parameter ``dico`` would replace ``d`` in the function's block: ``dico[ma.group(1)][0]`` and ``dico[ma.group(1)][1]``. Defining a default value for a parameter is interesting because the execution of a function's definition is executed only one time (by definition, you must understand: the block of text that describes the function)

Comment: @new2python What ``ripl`` returns must be a string: this one is used to replace each match (= matching portion) in the treated text. As ``ripl`` is a function, what it returns can vary from one match to another. The match (= matching portion) that is replaced is contained in the match(= MatchObject) that is passed to parameter ``ma`` : it is the ``ma.group(0)``. I mean that the regex pattern may have several groups defined in it, but the portion of text replaced, for each match, is the complete match (which is captured in ``group(0)`` even if there are no groups defined in the pattern)

Comment: @new2python My answer exposes only the manner to do several replacements in one pass, not what is concerning opening, reading and writing files. Once you have the replaced text, you'll do what you want with it.

Comment: @new2python My email address is on my user's page. But take care that its ey**g**uem@gmail.cpm, whereas on SO my pseduo is ey**q**uem. It's because on gmail, the name eyquem was already used